# MySQL Notifier High Severity Error at startup

Tags: mysql

When I start MySQL Notifier up, an error like this is shown:

> "High Severity Error"  "Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

And when I click over "`Show Details`" I can see the the program's exception stack trace:

> at MySQL.Utility.IniFile.HasKey(String section, String keyToFind)  at
>   MySql.Notifier.MySQLService.GetStartupParameters()  at
>   MySql.Notifier.MySQLService.FindMatchingWBConnections()  at
>   MySql.Notifier.MySQLService.SetServiceParameters(Boolean
>   doNotFetchInstanceIfOffline)  at
>   MySql.Notifier.Machine.LoadServiceParameters(MySQLService service,
>   ChangeType changeType)  at
>   MySql.Notifier.Machine.ChangeService(MySQLService service, ChangeType
>   changeType)  at MySql.Notifier.Machine.LoadServicesParameters(Boolean
>   setupWMIEventsOnly)  at
>   MySql.Notifier.MachinesList.LoadMachinesServices()  at
>   MySql.Notifier.Notifier..ctor()  at
>   MySql.Notifier.NotifierApplicationContext..ctor()  at
>   MySql.Notifier.Program.Main(String[] args)

What can I do to start the program correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error appears due to a corrupted configuration file or some dummy MySQL services (Leftovers from server installations not completely removed). Always **make sure** you're **running** the **latest Notifier** version available (that can be downloaded at [mysql download page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)).

**How to solve the corrupted file configuration:**

1. Open a Run command window and type the following (from Windows Vista to Windows 8.1):

   > %AppData%\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\
2. Delete the `settings.config` at the mentioned location.

**How to solve the dummy MySQL services leftovers:**

3. If the problem persists, open a Run command window and type the following:

   > `services.msc`
4. Take note of any MySQL service that shouldn't be listed (attempted uninstall before).
5. Open an Admin rights command window and type the command:

   > sc delete "< Dummy_service_name_here >".

Restart Notifier and see if that corrected the problem.

If a similar error still appears afterwards, check if the stack trace shows the word CreateScheduledTask somewhere, that would mean something is wrong when Notifier tries to add a schedule task at startup to check for updates of any installed MySQL product.

A workaround is to open in notepad the `settings.config` file that was re-generated. Inside the file, look for a property called `"AutoCheckForUpdates"` and change the default value of `"True"` for `"False"` and run Notifier again, as noted in [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,605658,605696#msg-605696).